# systematically determine which model is better on a specific dataset

Tags: machine-learning, cross-validation

In general, there is no silver bullet to choose a better machine learning model for all datasets.

However, I'm wondering, what if we fix a dataset including all the train/test set ahead of time.

Given supervised model $f_1, \cdots, f_n$, a labeled regression dataset $X, y$, the dataset is nicely split into training and testing(no out of distribution situation) and using RMSE as comparing metric. Is there any systematic way to determine which model will perform better, without actually fitting all $n$ models?

And nice properties of $f_i$ can be assumed. (E.g. we fix all the hyper-parameter ahead of time).

Let the $f_i$ be a CART(decision tree) and their max_depth is fixed with $i$.

Comment: Without some stated, quantitative assumptions about how the $f_i$ might be related, you have no basis to assess the behavior of $f_n$ even after observing all the preceding $f_i.$  This looks like a hopeless endeavor.  Likely you have a similar situation in mind for which more detailed information about the relationships among the $f_i$ is available.  If so, please supply that by editing your post.

Comment: I'm only doing some thought experiment, and what type of quantitative assumptions  of $f_i$ is going to help me? maybe let's focus on the CART(decision tree). and the difference across $i$ is max_depth is $i$. <- added to the description, is this enough to make the question meaningful ?@whuber

Comment: A further problem is that what you presumably want to find is a model that works well on new data from the same population. A single fixed train/test set might not provide such a model.

Comment: for simplicity, I'll make the goal as find the model performs the best only on the testing set.

Comment: @EdM or a different way to put it, I'm looking for an oracle to overfit the testing set without training the models.